# Set value of text box using val(value) doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which if checkbox of a row is clicked this row will be disable (mean all inputs be disable and value of text boxes are set to 0)

HTML

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    tableID = "tableID" + i;
    buttonAddID = "buttonAddID" + i;
    <table id="@tableID"  class="tableSum">
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>Apple</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>100</td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="highLightRow(this)" /></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="text" value="Organe" /></td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>200</td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="highLightRow(this)" /></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <td>Total</td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
           </tr>
             <tr><td colspan="4"><input type="button" class="addRow" onclick="addRow(this)" value="ADD ROW" id="@buttonAddID"/></td></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
}
```

In JS:

```
function highLightRow(cb) {
    var tr = $(cb).closest('tr');
    var inputs = tr.find('input[type=text]');
    if (cb.checked) {
        tr.removeClass('trNormal')
        tr.addClass('trHighLight');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].disabled = true;
            inputs[i].val('0');
        }
    }
    else {
        tr.removeClass('trHighLight')
        tr.addClass('trNormal');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The method `inputs[i].disabled = true;` works, text boxes are disable but the value is not set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert `DOMElement` to `jQuery` object like so

```
$(inputs[i]).val('0');
```

because `DOMElement` does not have `.val` method, or you can use [`.value`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) property from `DOMElement` , like so

```
inputs[i].value = '0';
```

[`.disabled`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp) works because this is `DOMElement` property

Answer (score 2):

For that line, use [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `[]`

```
inputs.eq(i).val('0');
```

What was happening is accessing an item like `inputs[i]` gives the native javascript DOM element which does not have a method `val()`. `eq()` however will retrieve the jQuery object. So, either use above or take the pure javascript alternative

```
inputs[i].value = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery each function:

```
inputs.each(function(){

    $(this).val('0');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq) and [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs.eq(i).prop('disabled',true);
            inputs.eq(i).val('0');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call `val()` function on javaScript DOM object, `val()` is not JavaScript Native method, it will only work with jQuery object, so you can call only with jQuery selector

```
$(inputs[i]).val('0');
```

Or you can also assign value in `value` variable,

```
inputs[i].value = '0';
```